# Pagination issues in php

Tags: php, mysql

When I click on class of year a student graduated as seen below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C4iX.png)

it takes user to the  students.php with the list of students graduated that year.

[image]

Then I use this piece of code to check and get the value from the members.php url string.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5GSq.png)

In the students.php page, I have a pagination implemented which is also redirecting to the same stud`enter code here`ents.php page

The problem is that when I click on the pagination numbers displayed on the students.php page, no data is returned in the same students.php page.
[image]

just wondering if the issue could be as result of this piece of code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXN1d.png)
 as it goes to check for the classof again in the url which no longer exist

My code on students.php is below:

```
$results_per_page = 2;

if (isset($_GET['classof']))
{
        // find out the number of results\records stored in the database

        $classof =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['classof']);


        $query = "SELECT *  from register where classof=? order by firstname asc";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('s', $classof);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->get_result();
        $number_of_results = $result->num_rows;
        $statement->close();

        // determine the number of total pages available
        $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);

         // determine which page number visitor is currently on
        if(!isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $page=1;
        }
        else
        {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }



    //determine the sql limit starting number for the results on the displaying page
    $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;

if ($number_of_results > 0 )
    {
        //retrieve selected results from database and display them on page.
        $sql = "SELECT *  from register where classof=? order by firstname asc LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $classof);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $usercount = $result->num_rows;
        //$statement->close();


          echo "
          <center>
        <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6 offset-md-3 form-div'>
        <h3 class='text-success'> Class of $classof </h3>
        <table class='table table-striped table-borderless table-hover'>
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
                <tr>
                    <th >Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Country of Residence</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>";




        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

         $userid = $row["id"];
         $firstname = $row["firstname"];
         $lastname = $row["lastname"];
         $country = $row["country"];

         echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$firstname</td>
                <td>$lastname</td>
                <td>$country</td>
                <td><a href='contact_student.php?userid=$userid'>Contact</a></td>

            </tr>";



        }
    }



        echo "</table>";

         // Display the link to the pages
        for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++)
        {
            //echo "
            //<tr>
            //";
            echo '<a href="students.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a>';
            //echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </center>";


}       



include ('includes/footer.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: please post errors with ```ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);```

Comment: I have added it but there are no errors. I t just that when I click the pagenation numbers, no resultsets are displayed

Answer (score 0):

In Sql you need to use LIMIT and OFFSET for pagination.

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table
LIMIT {PER_PAGE} OFFSET {LAST_ELEMENT_NUMBER_IN_PREV_PAGE};
```

Comment: My sql query has the LIMIT and OFFSET which has been defined in a variable. $sql = "SELECT *  from register where classof=? order by firstname asc LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;

Comment: I see that you use short limit syntax. Try to use `LIMIT %n OFFSET %n`, not `LIMIT %n, %n`

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve it by changing the below part of the script. All other part remains same.

Before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45DkO.png)

After change
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGDBs.png)